# Why does alert return an 'undefined' variable value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that dynamically adds an input and dropdown box when a '+' sign is clicked. However, when the dropdown is changed, the `alert` returns `undefined`. Why does it?

```
jQuery(document).change(".marker-drop-down", function() {       
    alert(jQuery(this).attr("id"));     
});

//functions
function addInputBox() {    
    jQuery("#insert-question-inbox").append('<div id="question-'+i+'-div">
<div id="remove-question-'+i+'" class="ui-icon ui-icon-minus remove-question"></div>
<input class="question-input" type="text" id=question-'+i+' value=question-'+i+' />
<select id="question-'+i+'-drop-down" class="maker-drop-down">
<option>Select</option><option value="multiple-choice">Multiple Choice</option>
<option value="select-all">Select all that apply</option></select><br /></div>');
    i += 1;     
}
```

Comment: What is `.marker-drop-down`? Show html code.

Comment: scroll to the right... you will see that it is in the append() within the javascript.

Comment: In append there is `class="maker-drop-down"`, in select there is `.marker-drop-down`. **maker-drop-down** != **marker-drop-down**

Comment: I do not see it there. That is why I asking you - what is `.marker-drop-down`??

Comment: You are referring to `jQuery(document)` for which you do not have defined the id thats why it is displaying undefined

Comment: Tushar - what is the solution then?

Comment: @massimorai `jQuery(".marker-drop-down").change(function(){        
        alert(jQuery(this).attr("id"));     
    });` but be sure that you have element with this class as you have a typo

Comment: @Cheery - it is the value of the <select class='.marker-drop-down'></select>

Comment: @massimorai I'm writing for the 3rd time - you do not have such class there. You have `maker-drop-down`, not `marker`

Comment: apart from typo, you need to use event delegation... so marking it as an duplicate

Comment: @massimorai because you appear to be missing it... your selector has **MARKER** and your HTML has **MAKER**

Comment: @Phil there is big difference between delegated `$(document).on("change", ".maker-drop-down", function() {` and simple `jQuery(document).change(".marker-drop-down", function() {` where `".marker-drop-down"` is just [eventData](http://api.jquery.com/change/), not delegated selector.

Comment: @Regent Doh! Totally missed that :(

Comment: @Phil yes, I've reread several times before I understand what is wrong :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use it as

```
$(document).on("change",".maker-drop-down", function(){        
        alert($(this).attr("id"));     
    });
```

Comment: I voted this up, but there is a misspelling of "marker-drop-down".

Comment: @HeadCode In OP's code, the HTML has *maker-drop-down* so this is correct

Comment: @Phil In the previous set of comments it was established that it is a misspelling, but frankly now I'm not sure which is the correct one.